# Cannot run Arquillian integration test with IntelliJ, but Maven works

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jboss, ejb, jboss-arquillian

We have a large web application project that is using EJB, JPA, GWT. Everything is running in a JBoss 7.1 server. 
We have Arquillian integration tests set up, which run well when launched through Maven (mvn verify), but I struggle to run them using IntelliJ JUnit test runner. Ask for any details you need, though I will not be able to provide everything - project is commercial. Thanks!

Here's the output:

```
[MANY BLOCKS OF ERRORS SIMILAR TO THE FIRST ONE:]
14:43:48,480 ERROR [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000177: Error in named query: ReportDefinition.findSectionBySectionId: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ReportSection is not mapped [SELECT reportSection FROM ReportSection reportSection WHERE reportSection.id.tid = :tid AND reportSection.sectionId = :sectionId]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3252) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3141) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:694) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:550) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:974) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:485) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

14:43:48,523 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa": Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: xyzJpa] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
[LOADS OF ENTITY NAMED QUERIES] ReportDefinition.findSectionBySectionId, 
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:494)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
... 9 more

14:43:48,748 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "xyzIntegration.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa\": Failed to start service"}}
14:43:48,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment xyzEJB.jar in 45ms
14:43:48,795 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.war in 46ms
14:43:48,825 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment xyzIntegration.ear in 77ms
14:43:48,827 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa": Failed to start service


java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke operation
at org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.ArquillianSuiteExtension$SuiteDeployer.executeInClassScope(ArquillianSuiteExtension.java:188)
at org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.ArquillianSuiteExtension$SuiteDeployer.deploy(ArquillianSuiteExtension.java:163)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:208)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:97)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Could not deploy to container: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa\": Failed to start service"}}
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:74)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.deploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:148)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.ArquillianSuiteExtension$SuiteDeployer$1.call(ArquillianSuiteExtension.java:167)
at org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.ArquillianSuiteExtension$SuiteDeployer$1.call(ArquillianSuiteExtension.java:163)
at org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.ArquillianSuiteExtension$SuiteDeployer.executeInClassScope(ArquillianSuiteExtension.java:186)
... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"xyzIntegration.ear/xyzEJB.jar#xyzJpa\": Failed to start service"}}
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getActionResult(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:134)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getResultFromNode(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:123)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:85)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:42)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.executeDeploymentPlan(ArchiveDeployer.java:91)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:58)
... 114 more
```

arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"></defaultProtocol>

    <container qualifier="jbossas-managed" default="true">
        <configuration>       
            <property name="serverConfig">standalone-test.xml</property>
        </configuration>

    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>${arquillian.junit.container}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.jboss.arquillian.protocol}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive</artifactId>
        <version>${org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eu.ingwar.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-suite-extension</artifactId>
        <version>${arquillian-suite-extension}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

hibernate.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>    
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

test-persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="xyzJpa">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/xyzdbtest</jta-data-source>
    <jar-file>lib/xyzJPA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar-file>


    <mapping-file>META-INF/jpql/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xml</mapping-file>


    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

@Deployment for every test contains:

```
    final EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "xyzIntegration.ear");

    JavaArchive[] xyzJPA = Maven.resolver().resolve("com.xyz:xyzJPA:" + SNAPSHOT_VERSION).withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);
    JavaArchive[] xyzClient = Maven.resolver().resolve("com.xyz:xyzClient:" + SNAPSHOT_VERSION).withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);
    JavaArchive[] xyzDTO = Maven.resolver().resolve("com.xyz:xyzDTO:" + SNAPSHOT_VERSION).withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);
    JavaArchive[] apacheCommonUtils3 = Maven.resolver().resolve("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:" + COMMONS_LANG_3_VERSION).withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);
    JavaArchive[] unitils = Maven.resolver().resolve("org.unitils:unitils-core:" + UNITILS_CORE_VERSION).withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);

    ear.addAsLibraries(xyzJPA);
    ear.addAsLibraries(xyzClient);
    ear.addAsLibraries(xyzDTO);
    ear.addAsLibraries(apacheCommonUtils3);
    ear.addAsLibraries(unitils);

    final JavaArchive ejbModule = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "xyzEJB.jar")
    //add packages
    //all Entity xmls added as Resource
    .addAsResource(new FileAsset(new File("../xyzJPA/src/main/java/com/xyz/xyz/jpql/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xml")), "META-INF/jpql/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xml")
    .addAsManifestResource(new FileAsset(new File("src/test/resources/META-INF/test-persistence.xml")), "persistence.xml")
    .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
    .addAsManifestResource(new FileAsset(new File("src/test/resources/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml")), "hibernate.cfg.xml");

    ear.addAsModule(ejbModule);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but does `hibernate.ejb.cfgfile` property need a value starting with slash? Like `"/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"`?

Comment: It seems that you are using both `persistence.xml` and `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Be aware of the potential clashes. The properties set in **persistence.xml** will override the one defined in the **hibernate.cfg.xml**.  There is no reason to mix them - you can express everything inside just on of them.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this error seems quite obvious:
`EntityManagerFactory` failed to start due to not mapped class name used in named query.

### First of all

- If you are using file `hibernat.cfg.xml` make sure that you have `ReportSection` listed in your mapped classes. Please **double check** that your persistence configuration file is included in your arquillian deployment like:

  ```
  JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
          .addPackages(true, "com.company.package")
          (...)
          .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
  ```
- Make sure that you are not mixing `javax.persistence.Entity` and `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` annotations.

### Secondly

Also, the other reason, might be a bug inside jboss adapter/ container - I've also encountered such. Please make sure that you are using **exactly the same** version of the JBoss when launching arquillian tests via maven as via IntelliJ - this is crucial (maybe IntelliJ has different classpath or is using some maven profile).
You  can also try a `remote` adapter or even another version of JBoss AS (e.g. WildFly 8.x) - just to make sure that your problem is not caused by some bug inside JBoss or Arquillian.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added contents of more files to my question - please take a look. 'test-persistence.xml' is added to jar as a manifest resource, as well as hibernate.cfg.xml.
I'm not sure what is the `ReportSection`, that you mentioned...

Comment: JBoss version 7.1.1.Final is used in both Maven and IntelliJ.

Comment: @ahumellihuk `ReportSection` is name of your entity, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized you were referring to that. Sorry. Entities are not listed in hibernate.cfg.xml, they are to be picked up automatically.